# Fetch Usage examples from vocabulary.com

Tags: java, web

I am trying create a simple text file in the below format `Word [TAB] Meaning [TAB] sentences`

I currently have a file containing word meanings in the format `Word [TAB] meaning`

Every time I want to study the example sentences for a particular word I have to search it on vocabulary.com

Lets say I'm searching for word "abase". Then the URL generated is `https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/abase`

The usage examples are shown on the right side of the page and i think they are  being fetched on the page using some script.

I want to create a program in java that reads words from the file I have on my laptop and then search it on vocabulary.com and fetch the first usage example sentence and write it to a text file.

I used a `URL` to get the page and then searching for the sentence in the `inputstream`, but this did not work as sentences were not fetched in the stream.

Comment: Have you read the tutorial for using a URL?  The example is pretty clear.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

Comment: I would suggest using Jsoup to accomplish this. You could find examples in their [cookbook](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/)

Comment: @Amir Afgani : I have gone through the mentioned URL and tried Reading from a URLConnection but it didn't work with vocabulary.com.

Comment: @JoshM : I have never worked with Jsoup. Will give it a try If you can link me to some specific similar example then that'll be of great help.

Comment: @JoshM : Just had a look at a quick example of jsoup and tried to work out this but still facing the same problem i.e. example sentences are not getting fetched
String url = "https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/abase";
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
System.out.println(doc.toString());

Comment: Try posting some more code.

Comment: @JoshM : Here is what i tried : http://ideone.com/XxnQWY
Basically my idea was that if it fetches the usage examples and can print on the console...then i can search through the fetched data for usage examples. But it never fetched the usage examples section